# Where can I find the guy that does the Phoenix implant?

Tags: fallout-2

Just curious about it, since I remember once met that medic who has the ability to do that implant at an expensive cost.

Where can I exactly find him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the phoenix implants after finding out about them from the medical database in the vault. Once you have knowledge of them you can speak to Doctor "Andrew" to find out more about them.

You can also get the Phoenix implants from the doctors that appear in Redding and San Francisco.

Both the combat and armour implant can be purchased and upgraded in these locations as detailed in the [Fallout 2 wikia article on implants](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_2_implants).